# Is Modern Warfare 3's 'Survival' mode a separate purchase on Steam?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When buying Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 through Steam, is there a separate purchase for it's 'Survival' mode?

Or does it come with the purchase of the game itself?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions. Simply click the delete link under the question; however, it is encouraged to post an answer to your question if you found the answer yourself (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Don't vandalize your question, please.  There's a delete button beside the Share, Edit, etc. buttons.  Use that instead of editing your question into something that's not even a question.

Comment: @Frank Only share edit and flag shows up.

Comment: You now have an upvoted answer to your question, meaning you can no longer delete your question.  That's why we don't allow vandalization of questions; because people go to the effort of answering them, and we don't want that effort to go to waste.

Comment: @John - There's nothing terrible that's going to happen if we keep the question, it may help future visitors who have the same question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MW3 survival is part of the game, so no, there is not a separate purchase.